# Installing python modules for specific version on linux (pySide)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, pyside

So, to keep it simple. Ubuntu 12.10 has python 3.2 pre installed and it is linked to "python3". I downloaded python 3.3 and it's command is "python3.3". However, I downloaded pySide for python3 from synaptic. Using "from PySide.QtCore import *" fails on python3.3. BUT, when I ran just "python3" (aka 3.2) everything works fine. Synaptic just installed lib for python3.2 which is default for python3 in ubuntu. How can I force synaptic to install modules for python3.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working in a virtual environment with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This will keep your python versions/packages separate from each other in case something goes wrong. Use pip to install PySide.

EDIT:

A possible solution is:

```
~$ sudo easy_install pip
```

To install virtualenv,

```
~$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

The page for [PySide](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide) on PyPi has a guide for different platforms on how to install pyqt with virtualenv. Best of luck.

Comment: [Pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is the python package manager. It will pull sources from pypi which is a package repository, and build for your version.

Comment: well I downloaded virtualenv, created env for 3.3, run pip from there to install pyside and it installed for default system's python - 2.7. I have no idea how to control it... Python is great but I have no clue how to install modules for 3.3, as that virtualenv didn't affect the pip.

Comment: You need to
```sh
~$ source venv/bin/activate
```
That will allow you to use the local pip.

Comment: Thanks. However, I found another option - python 3.3 ships with its own env tool by default! http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-405-virtual-environments

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install the pyside from its source files that have `setup.py` and then run the command `python3.3 setup.py build` and `sudo python3.3 setup.py install` because if you install by apt for example, it will use the default interpreter which is 3.2 that you mentioned.