# Python3.3 can't find libpython3.3m.so in OS X virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pyside, virtualenvwrapper

I have `IPython` with `qtconsole` installed in my system, but I'd like to build an independent `venv` with `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` as a sandbox in which to experiment before adding more stuff to my system, plus I wanted to experiment with `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` to understand them better, so I'm trying to build the same arrangement inside a `venv` and failing because I can't get `PySide` installed in the `venv`.

I read this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903321/python3-3-cant-find-libpython3-3m-so-in-linux-pip-3-3), as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895763/installing-python-modules-for-specific-version-on-linux-pyside/13895878#13895878), and I read the [PySide instructions for installing from source on Unix](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide), but none of these sets of guidance is working for me.

Obviously, I do have `PySide` installed in the system (OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard) itself via MacPorts (`py33-pyside @1.1.2_1 (active)`), and can run `ipython3 qtconsole` from the system (outside the `venv`), but installing `PySide` from source *inside* `venv` with `$ pip install PySide` is failing with:

```
...running install
running build
error: Failed to locate the Python library /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/libpython3.3m.so
```

And indeed, it's true:

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/
total 16
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     9 Sep 29 11:17 libpython3.3.dylib -> ../Python
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     9 Sep 29 11:17 libpython3.3m.dylib -> ../Python
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   170 Jan 11 12:33 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x  191 root  wheel  6494 Jan 11 12:33 python3.3
```

These `.dylib` files are from my MacPorts `python33` system installation:

```
$ sudo port provides /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/libpython3.3m.dylib 
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/libpython3.3m.dylib is provided by: python33
```

but I had the impression that `virtualenv` would cause new package installs to use resources that are independent of the system (other than initially with creation of the `venv` from system resources), so I guess I'm missing something important about how `virtualenv` isolates the `venv` from the system.

iptest3 status is OK for both system and `venv` (not sure if that matters).

What is it that's supposed to give me the `libpython3.3m.so` library? Maybe some development version of python3.3?

Answer (score 1):

If you link `libpython3.3m.dylib` to `libpython3.3m.so`, everything should work out (well, it has for me at least). `ln -s libpython3.3m.dylib libpython3.3m.so` in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/`. I think the trouble is that OS X uses `.dylib` for shared libraries, whereas *nix tends to use `.so` (although feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Ai'nt working for me either. Python3.2 and 2.7 have a libpython.so, but python3.3's got a libpython.a. linking does'nt work